# No consigo validar un rango de fechas determinada en mysql y php

Tags: mysql, php7

Estoy haciendo un calendario para poder agendar horarios que se puede usar cada sala, son 3 salas en total, el problema es la validación. Por ejemplo si agendaron la sala1 de 14 a 16 no se puede usar esa misma sala en ese horario, tendría que usar otra sala, he podido validar la hora de entrada con el siguiente código:

```
$q = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE sala = '$sala' AND inicio_normal = '$inicio_normal'");
```

Pero resulta que si una persona reserva la sala de 15 a 16 el sistema le permite y no debería, porque ya esta ocupada de 14 a 16.

El campo de la tabla hora de entrada y hora de salida es un DATETIME, toma el valor del campo input date, estoy usando un datetimepicker.

Asi me muestra en la base:
hora_inicial
2022-11-08 09:00:00

hora_final
2022-11-08 10:00:00

He probado con between de esa forma:

```
$q = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE sala = '$sala' AND (inicio_normal BETWEEN '$inicio_normal' AND '$final_normal') OR (final_normal BETWEEN '$inicio_normal' AND '$final_normal')");
```

$inicio_normal y $final_normal son las variables que recibo del formulario.

Ya probe de todo, y no me sale, estoy trabado :(

Comment: Y no tienes un problema de paréntesis en la última query?? como que falta un paréntesis englobando a ambos betwen

Comment: Ahi puse el parentesis pero igual me deja registrar en el rango de horario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás manejando un rango de fechas también se puede de esta manera:

```
$q = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM agenda 
WHERE class= '$clase' AND ((inicio_normal >= '$inicio_normal' 
AND inicio_normal <='$final_normal') 
OR (final_normal >= '$inicio_normal' AND final_normal <= '$final_normal'))");
```

Answer (score 0):

Al fin pude resolver de esa manera:

```
$q = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE class = '$clase' AND ((inicio_normal BETWEEN '$inicio_normal' AND '$final_normal') OR (final_normal BETWEEN '$inicio_normal' AND '$final_normal'))");
```

Por si alguien lo necesita

Comment: Es decir, sí era un problema de paréntesis :)

Comment: Hola, si, le puse los paréntesis como me dijiste, pero al momento no se que hice que no funciono, lo que pasa es que ya estaba mareado de probar tantas cosas, pero al final salió así como en la consulta. Muchas Gracias por su aporte